# Formatting a floating point variable in a SED statement

Tags: sed, floating-point

As part of a makefile recipe, I want to repeatedly adjust a few lines in some text file `txt.in`. In particular, I want to update, among others, the third line which contains simply two numbers separated by a space. They should be formatted as `0.00 0.00`. As such, I've included the code below in my makefile to test whether I can do this.

```sh
# Makefile to test for-loop
SHELL=/bin/zsh

for:
    for k in 1 2 3; do \
        let n="$$k*0.25"; \
        let m="$$n+0.25"; \
        sed -i "3s/.*/$$n $$m/" txt.in; \
    done
```

This yields `0.7500000000 1.0000000000` as the end result. There may be more efficient ways to do this and I'd be happy to find out about those, but the thing I'd really like to find out is if there's a way to get the format right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pipe the output through

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\{1,\}\.[0-9][0-9]\)[0-9]*\>/\1/g'
```

to get the desired format.  Effectively, your `sed` statement will change to:

```
sed -i "3s/.*/$$n $$m/" txt.in | sed -i 's/\([0-9]\{1,\}\.[0-9][0-9]\)[0-9]*\>/\1/g' txt.in; \
```

Comment: I see what you're getting at, but I'm afraid I still get the same result `0.7500000000 1.0000000000`. Adding the line `sed -i '3s/\([0-9]\{1,\}\.[0-9][0-9]\)[0-9]*\>/\1/g' txt.in; \ ` instead of using piping *does* work, any idea why this might be?

Comment: I see the problem and have fixed the answer.  The piping did not work on `txt.in`.

Comment: That works entirely as desired, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `printf`. This will give you zero padding for integer numbers even if your shell doesn't provide it:

```
o="$(printf "%.2f\n" "$$m")"
p="$(printf "%.2f\n" "$$n")"
sed -i "3s/.*/$$o $$p/" txt.in;
```